# Prove or refute these lemmas that I've deduced concerning examples to the Pólya class

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, complex-numbers, products, entire-functions

I did calculations using (simple reasonings with analysis and) the properties of the reference to get two lemmas.

> **Question.** Do you recognize if in my deductions and calculations there were mistakes? That is if some of my lemmas is wrong, then you can tell me where could be some mistake, and if the lemmas are rights provide me hints to do a comparison with my calculations. **Many thanks.**

Let $N\geq 1$ a fixed integer and we define the complex funtion $$f_N(z)=\prod_{n=1}^N e^{-(\rho_n-\frac{1}{2})(\frac{1}{2}-\rho_n)iz},$$  where we are denoting with $\rho_n$ a sequence of complex numbers with $\rho_n=\sigma_n+it_n$, that is $\Re\rho_n=\sigma_n$ and imaginary part $\Im\rho_n=t_n$, satisfying the conditions $0<\sigma_n<1$ and $0<t_n$, I mean when (for each integer $n$ in this segment) $1\leq n\leq N$.

> **Lemma 1.** $\forall N\geq 1$ the function $f_N(z)$ belongs to the [Pólya class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_class).

And this

> **Lemma 2.** If for each $1\leq n\leq N$, I say for all integers $n$ in our segment, the condtion $\Re\rho_n=\frac{1}{2}$ holds, then $$\Re\left(\frac{f'_N(z)}{f_N(z)}\right)=0.$$

Comment: If the lemmas are rights, as was said, only is required hints and key calculations to deduce the proofs, but it will be appreciated a full proof of both lemmas to do a comparison with my calculations. Thanks in advance. (Also if some user want to do feedback in comments about new simple lemmas or interesting facts that one can get for the sequence of $f_N$, and sequences $\rho_n$ is welcome to coment it here).